# Parameter @code1 has no default value

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I'm creating this code to use two comboboxes, one that depends on the first, but when I'm trying to select the "code_Zone" from the Table "Zone" I have this exception:

> Parameter @code1 has no default value

This is my code:

```
Dim cmd3 = New OleDbCommand("select [Code_Zone] from [Zone] where [Nom_Zone]= '@code';", connection)
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", ComboBoxNomZoneDeclaration.SelectedText.ToString)
Dim valeur = cmd3.ExecuteScalar
Dim commande = New OleDbCommand("select [Code_Cable] from [CableEnFibre] where [Code_Zone]=@code1;", connection)
commande.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code1", valeur)
Dim reader = commande.ExecuteReader   'there is the exception 
While reader.Read
    ComboBoxPanneCentreAppel.Items.Add(reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Code_Cable")))
End While
reader.Close()
```

Comment: You don't need the `'` around the parameter name in the query when you use Parameters. And the string in the query should be `@code1`

Comment: @OneFineDay you are correct but the wrong step is the quote around `@code` not `@code1` parameter. That produces no result from the first ExecuteScalar and then the error message in the second query when he tries to use the variable valeur that is probably equal to Nothing

Comment: @Steve, see that now!

Comment: @Steve yes of course I know that, but I can't understand why the combox selectText is empty while i'm sure I am choosing a correct value?

Comment: @BenChaabenWissem putting single quotes around `'@code'` transform this in a literal string. Is no more a parameter placeholder. Now when you execute the cmd3 query the database engine search the column Nom_Zone for the string `"@code"` and of course nothing is found. So the value of the variable `valeur` is nothing. Whatever is selected in the combobox is simply ignored

Comment: @Steve, i delete the simple quotes but nothing change . ComboBoxNomZoneDeclaration.SelectedText return empty value however my combobox is not impty this is  my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the first problem are the quotes around the `@code` parameter placeholder. In this way the placeholder is treated as a literal string. Now when you execute the `cmd3` command the database engine search the column `Nom_Zone` for the string `"@code"` and of course nothing is found. So the value of the variable `valeur` is nothing. 
Whatever is the selected text in the combobox is simply ignored.

And now the second problem. As you can [read in MSDN about SelectedText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx) this property is not the correct one to use if you want to retrieve the content of the current SelectedItem when the combo has not the focus

> ...you should be aware that the selection can change automatically
>   because of user interaction. For example, if you retrieve the
>   SelectedText value in a button Click event handler, the value will be
>   an empty string. This is because the selection is automatically
>   cleared when the input focus moves from the combo box to the button.

So you should use the SelectedItem property or the SelectedValue depending on how you have filled the ComboBox. Please use the debugger setting a breakpoint at the point where you are trying to read the value of the combo and check the value of your properties at that point